# Retaining UITouch: allowed or not?

Tags: ios, uikit, uiresponder

Here's a quote from the [documentation of `UITouch`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch):

> A touch object persists throughout a multi-touch sequence. **Never
>   retain a touch object when handling an event.** If you need to keep
>   information about a touch from one touch phase to another, copy that
>   information from the touch.

And then here's another one from [Event Handling Guide for UIKit Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/HandlingTouchesinYourView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH16-SW1):

> Listing 9-1 shows the main implementation of the TouchableView class
>   and its touch handling methods. Each method iterates through the
>   touches and performs the needed actions. The touchViews dictionary
>   uses the UITouch objects as keys to retrieve the subviews being
>   manipulated onscreen.

```
class TouchableView: UIView {
    var touchViews = [UITouch:TouchSpotView]()
    ...
}
```

Clearly, they're violating their own rules by using `UITouch` instances as dictionary keys...

So what's the deal with this? Should one retain `UITouch` instances for complex gesture tracking or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a bug report with Apple regarding the inconsistency between the sample code and the UITouch documentation. The result is that the paragraph "Never retain a touch object when handling an event" has been removed from the [UITouch documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch). Since the [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/implementing_a_custom_gesture_recognizer/implementing_a_discrete_gesture_recognizer) retains UITouch objects, we can therefore assume that it is allowed.

Comment: Wow! Apple actually listened to developer feedback?! :O

Answer (score 1):

Apple developers aren't perfect and yes I would agree they are violating their own guidelines. Similarly Apple say you should not subclass collection views, but I have done so before, for adding some minor utility functions, with no adverse effects. I would say this should be put in a similar category of "don't do it." If they have said don't do it, you do so at your own risk. But actually since it would be so easy to create proxy NSTouch records, why not do that anyway? For a similar reason I ended up "factoring" my collection view utility functions out into another utility class, just because I'm anal and wanted to be sure I was safe ;)